# Disable CSS and JS from a contributed module

Tags: 8, theming

I am using [Simple Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_megamenu) module.

I want to disable the CSS and JS provided by this contributed module:

- modules/contrib/simple_megamenu/js/simple_megamenu.js
- modules/contrib/simple_megamenu/css/style.css

In the module description the say

> Simple Mega Menu provide basic styling. You can override the library
>   (css/js) provided by this module simply by adding theses lines into
>   your theme file my_theme.info.yml

```
libraries-override:
  # Replace an entire library.
  simple_megamenu/base: my_theme/megamenu
```

How do I *disable* the CSS and JS files properly in `my_theme.info.yml`?

Answer (score 1):

I think setting the library to `FALSE` should work:

```
libraries-override:
  # Replace an entire library.
  simple_megamenu/base: false
```